# General function Input array

Tags: c

I can't figure what is wrong here. This is supposed to be a function to read from the user the size of array and then pass it to function to start fill the array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int input_array(int *start, int s_size);

int main()
{
    int arr_size;

    printf("Please enter the Size of your array: ");
    scanf("%d",&arr_size);

    int arr[arr_size];

    input_array(arr,arr_size);

    return 0;
}
int input_array(int *start, int s_size)
{
    static int counter=0;

    printf("Start fill your array with %d elements: \n\n",s_size);

    for(counter=0; counter<s_size; counter++)
    {
        printf("Input Element : ");
        scanf("%d",start[counter]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return start[0];
}
```

[image: this is the error I get when I run the program]

Comment: `scanf` wants the address-of `&` operator for its parameters. Chapter 1 in your favourite C programming for beginners book.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings at their highest level

Answer (score 4):

In you function `int input_array(int *start, int s_size)` this statement

As `start` is `int *` -

```
scanf("%d",start[counter]);        // pass address of variable
```

you need to pass address of `start[counter]` because it is of type `int` .

Comment: lol, I got that too, but could not come up with the right syntax to get the address of the indirected, indexed int :)

Comment: @MartinJames Umm , sorry but I don't quite understand what are you trying to say :)

Comment: I know what's wrong, but not how to correctly fix it:(

Comment: Ok I got the error it is in this line 

    scanf("%d",start[counter]);

should be 

scanf("%d",&start[counter]);

Comment: @MartinJames Why whats wrong with passing `&start[counter]` ?

Comment: @MinaNagy Well , glad for you.

Comment: @ameyCU - probably nothing.  It's just that I have problems with the confusing way C treats arrays and pointers.

Comment: @MartinJames Agreed ,it is problem for many including me somethimes :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer that this line

```
scanf("%d",start[counter]);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d",&start[counter]);
```

the and '&' operator was missig

Comment: or just `start + counter`